# Joomla 2.5 onAfterInitialise event not being triggered

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I'm trying to write a single-signon extension so that our MediaWiki users with the correct permissions don't need to log in to our Joomla 2.5. I can't get it to work, because the onAfterInitialise event won't trigger (neither does onAfterRoute or onAfterDispatch if I try to use those instead). I know the extension is actually running because the onUserAuthentication event is triggering and logging me in as my test user.

Below is my code with the two events, the first won't trigger and execute the die() statement, the second triggers after login and unconditionally authenticates me properly.

Is there something I'm missing here like that one extension can't use two different categories of events or something?

```
class plgAuthenticationMwSSO extends JPlugin {

    function __construct( &$subject, $config ) {
        parent::__construct( $subject, $config );
    }

    public function onAfterInitialise() {
        die('testing');
    }

    public function onUserAuthenticate( $creds, $opt, &$response ) {
        $response->username = 'Foo';
        $response->fullname = 'Foo Bar';
        $response->email = 'foo@bar.baz';
        $response->status = JAuthentication::STATUS_SUCCESS;
        $response->error_message = '';
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! You might get more details and more answers by asking at dedicated site [http://joomla.stackexchange.com/](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks Elin! that was the problem, I've made it into a package of two plugins now which is working. Thanks miroxlav too for the link, that's got a lot of good info there :-)

Comment: I'm going to make that an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the `onAfterInitialise` in a system plugin. As a parallel example, notice how the Remember plugin is a **system** plugin and then the Cookie plugin is an **authentication** one. System plugins are checked very early in the stack and are checked on every page load. Authentication plugins are checked when authentication starts and are specifically loaded as a group at certain times. Since you have an authentication plugin, it  is not triggered at the right time to respond to the system events that you are looking for.

Comment: It's working now, it turned out that I didn't need to use an authentication plugin at all, I just used $session->set in the onAfterInitialise event so that the onUserAuthenticate is never even called :-)